# Printer Samsung ML-2165W: Installed but it won't print (13.04)

Tags: 13.04, printing, samsung

I couldn't make printer Samsung ML-2165W work for Ubuntu 13.04. I had general Linux driver from Samsung installed. The installation was successful, printer didn't print a test page.

Answer (score 1):

The same issue here, although I got it running under ubuntu 12.04 LTS with linux drivers from Samsung. With 13.04, however, Samsung drivers are not installing properly any more. As a workaround, you could try Samsung driver packages from the http://bchemnet.com/suldr/ repository (look at the suld-drivers-4.00.39 package specifically).

Answer (score 1):

this is instructions for wifi setup on 64bit, based on these [full instructions](http://ro-che.info/articles/2014-04-21-wireless-samsung-printer-linux):

```
 sudo useradd --create-home --shell /bin/bash --groups lp samsung
 xhost +local:samsung #as a X app will be run
 sudo su - samsung
 wget http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/DR/201110/20111019151150392/PSU_1.01.tar.gz
 tar xzf PSU_1.01.tar.gz
 cd cdroot/Linux/wirelesssetup

 ldd bin64/wirelesssetup  | grep 'not found' #if it outputs something...
 # apply these fixes (find these files with `mc` and create these proper symlinks to them as shown below)
 #tar -xf libstdc++-5-x86_64.tar.gz 
 ln -s libnetsnmp.so.10.0.2 libnetsnmp.so.10
 ln -s libqt-mt.so.3.0.5 libqt-mt.so.3
 ln -s libqui.so.1.0.0 libqui.so.1

 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="`pwd`/../psu/share/lib64/"
 bin64/wirelesssetup /dev/usb/lp0 #the application will open on X

 sudo passwd -d samsung
 passwd samsung #create a proper password if you want to keep that user or
 sudo userdel --remove samsung #delete it
```